# manipulando um array para montar a grid

Tags: php

Tenho um array em php e preciso ir agrupando os valores para conseguir colocalos em uma 
table>phtml

[Segue jsonArray](https://jsonblob.com/96fe33c5-8536-11e8-9013-6d24edb76e60)
Sempre terá esses cinco tipo de transporte.

Não consegui fazer muita coisa para deixar aqui o que já foi feito, a única coisa que tenho é

```
public function relatorio($dtInicio, $dtFinal) {
        $dbControleVeiculos = new \Db\Fisc\ControleVeiculos();
        $original = iterator_to_array($dbControleVeiculos->getResumoControleVeiculos($dtInicio, $dtFinal));

        $result = array();
        foreach ($original as $data) {
            $id = $data['nome'];
            if (isset($result[$id])) {
                $result[$id][] = $data;
            } else {
                $result[$id] = array($data);
            }
        }

        return $result;
        // return 
    }
```

O meu objetivo é que fique assim.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Se for o índice sum, você poderia fazer assim:

```
if (isset($result[$id])) {
     $result[$id][] = $data;
     $result[$id]['sum_total] += $data['sum']
} else {
     $result[$id] = array($data);
     $result[$id]['sum_total] += $data['sum']
}
```

Mas ficaria mais organizado, se desse groupBy pelo nome.
Depois poderia fazer o foreach mais completo +/- assim:

```
foreach($original as $nome => $data) {...}
```

Aonde esse nome, seria um índice com o valor do seu nome em questão